# Specify what network connection to use based on IP being accessed

Tags: windows-7, ip, ip-address, nic

Basically, we have a number of machines with two network cards. One is wireless, one is not.

The wireless is connected to the internet, while the other one is connected to a route and a bunch of internal computers.

Is there a way to set the machine to use the wireless when accessing any IP except 192.168.*.* and if the ip accessed is 192.168.*.* to use the other connection?

All these workstations (over 40) are running Windows 7, and we added a special wifi-4G NIC to some computers that need faster internet speeds (we are running two T1s, so the 4g is faster).

Comment: definitely going to need the os if you want a direct answer

Comment: There should be nothing special you need to do. The default route should carry Internet traffic to the connection that has Internet access. The network router, added automatically, should carry traffic for the internal network to the interface connected to that network. (If not, add a static route.)

Comment: Ugh, get business-class cable or DSL (in addition to the T1s if need be.  I'm in the same boat as you (being stuck with T1 connections)... and man, do I ever hate T1`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify a static route on the host.  Assuming the network is 192.168.0.0/24 you would add the following:

route add 192.168.0.0 gw

Depending on the distro would determine where you add it for persistence.

Comment: thanks bud, that should work. however, the 192 network also has internet access. How can I stop the workstation from accessing the internet through that network. ideally I'd like to define a static route to the wifi for all ips except 192.168.0.0/24. is there a good method for doing this?